# Compare month in nested object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The following problem is causing me some headache. I'm building an application to compare transaction data with a list of tenants and what they're supposed to pay for rent.
I've got it running nicely except it compares EACH transaction with the monthly rent. What I want to do is first add all (relevant) transaction amounts per month and then compare them.

Should I just build another nested `for`-loop to compare all the transaction months before I run this loop? I could potentially drop in years of transaction data making it quite inefficient...

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

```
  var table = "<table><thead><tr><th>Rek</th><th>Name</th><th>Date</th><th>Amount</th><th>Rent</th><th>Diff</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tenant.length; j++) {
      if (tenant[j].reks.indexOf(data[i].rek) == -1)
        continue;
      else {
        var diff = tenant[j].rent - data[i].amount; //TODO monthly!!!
        var style = " style='background-color: ";
        if (diff > 0)
          style += "red;'";
        else
          style += "green;'";

        table += "<tr><td>" + data[i].rek
          + "</td><td>" + data[i].name
          + "</td><td>" + (data[i].date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + data[i].date.getFullYear()
          + "</td><td>&euro; " + data[i].amount
          + "</td><td>&euro; " + tenant[j].rent
          + "</td><td" + style
          + ">" + diff
          + "</td></tr>";
      }
    }
  }
  table += "</tbody></table>";

  $('#top').html(table);
```

Comment: To make it more efficient, you can brake the tenant loop once you create a table row for the respected data, so that it does not continue looping once it find the value. And then you can delete that row from tenant object, so that there are less no. of rows to traverse next time.

Comment: @MohitPandey I can't do that, there can potentially be hundreds of transactions from the same tenant.